# Bringing diamond jewellery to Canada

Tags: canada, taxes, imports

I have a permanent residency in Canada. I want to bring 3 pieces of diamond jewelry with me when I move  costing 3000, 7000 and 11000 Canadian dollar. How much duty will I have to pay?

Comment: Are you asking about bringing the jewellery with you when you move to Canada? Or about going on a visit from Canada and bringing jewllery back with you?

Comment: This is for when i move to canada

Comment: If the jewellery is yours, intended for your personal use, not new, and not going to be resold then you don't have to pay duty. I'll post a complete answer when this is migrated to Expatriates. Or you could post the question again on Expatriates site, which is where it is best suited.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Canadian border services agency](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/pdt-pdt-eng.html), the duties and taxes can vary a bit.
In particular, in addition to any duties you may also need to pay appropriate sales tax etc for your province or residence.

As this can be complex, they also provide a calculator to **estimate** this:
https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/dte-acl/est-cal-eng.html

Currently (4th january 2019) this provides a tax estimate of $2924.25 for the details you have given.

Comment: If i am correct the tax is on the piece costing 11000. Right????

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is a 12% of everything more than CAN$60 (eq CAN$2512,8 in your case) if it wasn't originaly moved from Canada before (has Canadian origin).

But even in case it was from Canada and you somehow altered/improved/modified it, then it also is a subject for tax.

Comment: The $60 threshold is for gifts sent to other people according to their website. Personal exemption thresholds can be considerably higher if overseas for a while.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first trip to Canada as part of your settlement, that is, starting a household, your personal, household goods can be imported (mostly) free from duty and taxes. The information is [here](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/mrc-drc-eng.html).

The information specific to jewelry includes:

> Describe each item of jewellery you plan to bring into Canada on the list of goods you submit. Since jewellery is difficult to describe accurately, it is best to use the wording from your insurance policy or jeweller's appraisal and to include photographs that have been dated and signed by jeweller or gemologist. This makes it easier to identify the jewellery when you first enter Canada, and later when you return from abroad with the jewellery.

You have to fill out a complete list of the household goods that you're bringing in with you or that will follow later.